# How to enable average sorting including empty members

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sql-order-by

I need to sort by average value of the member and then get objects which can not be calculated by average function (empty collection). I tried to write something like this:

```
        var userPhotos =
            Database.Set<Photo>().Where(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) || p.ClientProfileId == userId).ToList();
        IOrderedEnumerable<Photo> sortedPhotos;
        switch (orderBy)
        {
            case OrderBy.Raiting:
                sortedPhotos = userPhotos.Where(p => p.Votes != null && p.Votes.Any()).OrderByDescending(item => item.Votes.Average())
                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.TimeOfCreation);
                break;
            default:
                sortedPhotos = userPhotos.OrderByDescending(item => item.TimeOfCreation);
                break;
        }
        return sortedPhotos.Skip((page - 1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

I need to include objects which have `> 0 votes`, but it doesn't work properly. Where is my mistake? Thanks for future answers!

Comment: how does it not work? is it throwing an exception? Do you want to include items that have no votes?

Comment: Exactly! I want to add items that have zero votes count after descending by votes was completed.

Comment: What is the type of `Photo.Votes`? Can you show the entity classes?

Comment: Of course. The type of votes is simple: `public ICollection<double> Votes { get; set; }`. Specify it purchase the concrete class in constructor: `Votes = new List<double>();`

Comment: sortedPhotos = userPhotos.OrderByDescending(item => item.Votes == null ? -1 : item.Votes.Average())

Comment: InvalidOperationExeception: sequence contains no elements.

Comment: Do you want the query to be executed in memory or on the database? Since you are invoking `ToList` in the first line. The reset of the code runs in memory.

Comment: I am not sure if you can have `ICollection<double>` with line to entities. Does that actually work? are the votes being saved to the database?

Comment: I really don't need to execute database data in memory. `ToList` method was written for avoding "NotSupportedExecption": "The specified type member 'Votes' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported". I just need to order my items by average rating. So I've created the member `Votes` to store all votes by users in database. The problem is with photos that have no votes yet.

Comment: I don't think that `ICollection<double>` would work? Do you actually see the votes data in the database?

Comment: Sure. It works correctly. It saves votes by users properly. Why do you asking? Is it not good way to store datas like that?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce. I am using entity framework. When I use `ICollection<double>`, no data is stored in the database.

Comment: how do you store data like theese in database? Probably it is my problem..? When I look at my database I can not observe the `votes` column. But when I return this object I can see the member `votes` and it `count`.

Comment: And you see a count > 0?

Comment: Yep. I can not download the screen in comment, but I can see all votes I've done. Also, evertyhing works with photos that have `votes count >0`. My problem is when photo has no votes. It doesn't including by my code in to the `sortedPhotos` object.

Comment: Are you using entity framework? which version?

Comment: I'm thinking about adding 0.00000...1 rating to the photo while it creating. But it is crutch or how do you say it in English..?

Comment: The version is 6.1.3. The latest stable version.

Comment: By the way, it doesn't matter. How to sort my items by average votes data?:) Or do I need to create one more member with average value and calculate it from votes data?

Comment: If the data is in memory as it is now, you can try `sortedPhotos = userPhotos.OrderByDescending(item => (items.Votes == null || items.Votes.Count == 0) ? -1 : item.Votes.Average())`

Comment: @YacoubMassad It works, but I think this code looks much better: `sortedPhotos = userPhotos.OrderByDescending(item => (item.Votes == null || !item.Votes.Any()) ? 0 : item.Votes.Average());` You can post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
sortedPhotos =
    userPhotos
    .OrderByDescending(item =>
        (item.Votes == null || !item.Votes.Any())
        ? -1
        : item.Votes.Average());
```

The idea is that for photos that don't have any votes, we give them an average vote of -1 (or some other special value that we know is less that what real votes can give you).